Delete features with arcade attribute rules (cut and paste)
I tried to redo it all on a new featureclass.
I tried deleting features witting the wfitting_a. So when the field A_CONSERVER of a feature is changed to the value 0, 2 or 3,
I get an error message.
The script below works only when I insert a new feature in the featureclass. When I update the table or insert a new feature, the other features that have a value of 0, 2 or 3 are deleted.
In your script you use WID and CODE as fields, what do they correpond to?

It seems you have followed the coding style of this post. I think a key issue is where are you placing your script? This poster suggests it must be on insert or update a new feature.

Looks like you are trying to apply the deletes on an update trigger? I'm guessing your trigger has been triggered by a row that is also a row that you want to delete. How can you update a row if it is to be deleted? You need to consider that in your logic.

Indeed I have checked the update trigger. Isn't it what you are doing in your script though?

In my sample script the update trigger is on field CODE, it gets global ids when another field called WID is 0,2 or 3. So it returns CODE, itself and applies the deletes.

Ok this code worked for me, it deleted some points in a layer when I updated a field in another layer. I believe the issue was to do with what you passed out for deletes, which was not the list of globalids you were creating. Also you were stepping over fs as f but then referencing $feature. I hope it is obvious that WID and CODE are fields in my datasets not yours!
var fs = FeatureSetByName($datastore, "fcExmoorWindfarms"); // This is the FeatureClass name not layer name!

// Collect globalids into an array called deletes
var deletes = [];
for(var f in fs) {
  if (f.WID == 0 || f.WID == 2 || f.WID == 3) {
    Push(deletes, {'GLOBALID': f.globalid})
  }
}

// return the value for the field that I updated (don't want to change that) but also correctly return array of globalids in deletes
return {
  'result': $feature.CODE,
  'edit': [
    {
      'className': 'fcExmoorWindfarms',
      'deletes': deletes
    }
  ]
}

Here is how I had set up the calculate attribute rule:


@DBeau Everything looks OK to me, do you get an error message with the new code, if so what is it?

When the 'deletes' is set to delete I get the error message above. I changed it to "f.globalid" (see change in code above) I dont get any error message but it doesn't update the table.

I've got a question. You say "it deleted some points in a layer when I updated a field in another layer". I'm not sure i understand. Because what I'm trying to do first is to cut the feature from the wsystemvalve feature class. So it is when I updated the field "LG" to 0, 2 or 3 that the point has to to be deleted from the wsystemvalve feature class. The table wsystemvalve_a is not included in the cutting or the update part.

@DBeau in your return statement you return f.globalid it needs to be the array deletes, review my code in my answer.

@DBeau do both your layers have a globalid field? If not you need to add it.

sorry to bother again, i have some improvment but it is not fully working. I updated my post
